# rails 4 post#method_missing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I simply want to add a user_id to a comment on a Post. When I change things a get different errors, but all provided solutions didn't help me.

I use the RailsApp with Devise.

CommentsController

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController  
before_action :authenticate_user!, :except => [:show, :index]  

def index
@comments = Comment.all
end

def new
end

def create
 @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
 @comment = @post.Comment.new(comment_params)

if @comment.save
 format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post), notice: 'Comment was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @comment.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end  

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_comment
  @comment = Comment.find(params[:id])
end

def set_user
  @user = current_user
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def comment_params
  params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :post_id, :user_id)
end
end
```

Add-on:
After the change provide by RSB I still got an error (too few arguments). I Changed the controller and now it works.

```
if @comment.save
respond_to do|format|
format.html { redirect_to post_path(@post)}
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @post }
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: @post.Comment.new(comment_params) or @post.comments.new(comment_params)??

Comment: What kind of errors are you getting?

Comment: Could you please **always** provide a full error message and a stacktrace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking your association between posts and comments as `has_many` and assuming that `user_id` column is present in your `comments` table, do this way

```
@comment = @post.comments.new(comment_params)
@comment.user_id = current_user.id
```

Comment: Well, it helps a bit. I now get this error: ArgumentError at /posts/1/comments, too few arguments

Comment: The answer of RSB Worked. Tnx. Now I have a problem with the redirect_to post_path(@post). This, I must and will resolve myself.